# PHP Array For Each not reading $_POST['item'] data

Tags: php, arrays

The following code is not

```
<?php
$deletinglist = addQuotes($_POST['delimglist']);
$deletelist = array($deletinglist);

foreach ($deletelist as $filename) {
unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . "/uploads/" . $filename);
}
function addQuotes($string) {
    return '"'. implode('","', explode(',', $string)) .'"';
}
?>
```

Here `$_POST['delimglist'] = "C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b932.jpg,C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b934.jpg,C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b935.jpg";`

If I use `$deletelist = array("C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b932.jpg","C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b934.jpg","C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b935.jpg");`

Its working fine but if I use `$deletelist = array($deletinglist);` its not working.

I am getting the following Warning when trying to use like the above

```
Warning: unlink(/home/...somepath.../uploads/"C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b932.jpg","C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b934.jpg","C0d49a7de7b635477125ffffa8df7b935.jpg"): No such file or directory in /home/...somepath.../deletefile.php on line 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you add quotes around filename?
The code should be as simple as this:

```
<?php
$deletelist = explode(',', $_POST['delimglist']);

foreach ($deletelist as $filename) {
    unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . "/uploads/" . $filename);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you're doing is putting `$deleteList` into an array as a single element. You want to separate the values by ','. Use `$deleteList = explode(',', $deleteList);`

Answer (score 1):

The following are not the same thing:

```
$arr1 = Array("a", "b", "c");

$str  = "a,b,c";
$arr2 = Array($str);
```

The commas in the first example are a language construct: writing them inside a single variable does not mean they magically gain language construct abilities; inside the string they are just characters.

Similarly, this:

```
$str = "a,b,c";
foo($str);
```

is the same as this:

```
foo("a,b,c");
```

and not this:

```
foo("a", "b", "c");
```

You will have to use a function that explicitly splits up the string `$_POST['delimglist']`:

```
$deleteList = explode(',', $_POST['delimglist']);
```